# Tesseract API c++ program built with visual studio 2019 on windows 10 crashes on windows server 2012

Tags: c++, tesseract, windows-server-2012-r2

Im am using the tesseract api (version 4) in a c++ program and build it using visual studio 2019 on windows 10. The executable runs fine on other windows 10 machines, but on windows server 2012 it crashes. The c++ runtime is correctly installed, other c++ programs work fine.
Does anybody have an idea what might be the cause and how to fix this?

Comment: You probably need to use a debugger and debug on the windows server 2012.

Comment: Crashes how?  Any message?

Comment: You presumably have some form of undefined behaviour which happens to not crash on your other machines. Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause: It is most probably related to tesseract bug:
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/3044

It happens when on virtual servers or older systems there is no SSE CPU flag (whatever that means) and the buildfiles are doing something wrong.

So there is no easy fix at the moment :-(

Comment: You should be able to resolve this by compiling with `/arch:IA32`.   You might also need to specify `/Os`.